# Can you export materials made in blender using nodes to another program?

Tags: texturing, normal-map

I am a beginner to blender and don't really have the knowledge to know if this is a silly question or not but here it goes.

When creating assets in blender is is possible to use the texture sets you have made with the node editor in blender and then exporting them for use in a engine.

Is it really as simple as saving the individual maps such as Diffuse, AO, Metallic etc as image textures and then importing them into your engine of choice for example Marmoset, Unity or Daz?

Comment: Probably some details stay out of question however yes, generally it is as simple as saving individual maps as you mention that you want to use in third-party software

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541